# Polymorphism on structs without methods in Go

Tags: go, polymorphism, web-development-server

I'm working on several web server projects in Go, and there is a common problem that I'm always facing. I know we can achieve something like polymorphism in Go with interfaces and methods, but many times I had a scenario that I needed polymorphism on some data-holder structs that (maybe) just had some common fields, and no methods at all.

For example consider a story writing platform, where each user can write short stories and novels:

```
type ShortStory struct {
    Name string
    ID   int
    Body string
}

type LongStory struct {
    Name     string
    ID       int
    Chapters []string
}
```

Now I simply want to have a data layer function, say `GetStories()`, which fetches all stories written by a user from database.

```
func GetStories(id int) []SOME_TYPE {
    ...
}
```

There are really no methods that I want to have on my `ShortStory` and `LongStory` structs. I know I can add a dummy method and let them satisfy some `Storier` interface, then use that interface as return type. But since there is no method I would want on a data container model, adding a dummy method just for the language to enable a feature, seems like a poor design choice to me.

I can also make the function return `[]interface{}`, but that's against the whole idea of "typed language" I believe.

Another way is to have two separate `GetShortStories()` and `GetLongStories()` methods, which return a slice of their own type. But at some point I would finally want to merge those two slices into one and there I would again need a `[]interface{}`. Yes, I can return a JSON like:

```
{
    "short_stories" : [...],
    "long_stories" : [...]
}
```

But I want my json to be like:

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

And I wouldn't change my APIs because of a language's limits!

I'm not a pro in Go, so am I missing something here? Is there a **Go-ish** approach to this, or is it really bad language design on Golang's side?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot express what you want to do using the features of a language, you should first try to change the way you structure your program before blaming the language itself. There are concepts that cannot be expressed in Go but can be expressed well in other languages, and there are concepts you cannot express well in other languages but you can in Go. Change the way you solve the problem to effectively use the language.

One way you can address your problem is using a different type of struct:

```
type Story struct {
    Name     string
    ID       int
    ShortBody string
    Chapters []string
}
```

If the `Chapters` is empty, then it is a short story.

Another way:

```
type Story struct {
   Name string
   ID int
   Content StoryContent
}

type StoryContent interface {
   Type() string
}

type ShortStory interface {
   StoryContent
   Body() string
}

type LongStory interface {
   StoryContent
   Chapters() []string
}
```

etc.

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem, because both the ways are actually workarounds, not solutions. The first one introduces an idea similar to Unions (and here they don't even save the memory), and it is not scalable if I try to add 5 more fields to my ShortStory and LongStory structs. The second one is again adding methods when there is no need for them. I don't think we can blame everything on the code design here. A framework may force you to for example have a "id" field in your classes to work, but Go is a language, and I think a language shouldn't force you to write codes that you don't need.

Comment: How would you design this in Java? Or C? The implementation of an object model will be slightly different in each language. The problem is that you are conflating implementation constraints with the design of a solution. I'd argue that your short/long story design is wrong, because a short story can be represented using a long story with a single chapter.

Comment: In OOLs you can have polymorphism just based on common data, not common actions. Btw the question is not about this scenario in particular. It's about the need of polymorphism when there are no shared methods between your structs. Change the example to "fetching ten different kind of users from db" or "fetching ten different kind of animals from db, when they don't walk() or bark() etc". There are just data models. @BurakSerdar

Comment: Go is not an object-oriented language. Polymorphism based on common data relies on downcasting, which eliminates compile-time type-safety. Again: how would you do this with no methods in Java? A common base with downcasting. Do the same in Go: return an interface{}, and use type assertions.